# Use inline HTML in R sapply() function

Tags: r, shiny, sapply

I am very noob in coding and R, so I am sorry if this is stupid.

In shiny, I run multiple `helpText` on my sidebarPanel so I tried to use sapply to make less repetitions of the function. It works great, except for the texts where I use inline HTML (as the `helpText` function allows).

Do you know how I can still keep some formating in `sapply`? Here is the part of my code that i want to update:

```
# Help text
        helpText(h3("FAQ")),
        lapply(
          c(
            "text",
            "more text"
          ),
          helpText
        ),
        helpText(h3("Title")),
        lapply(
          c(
            "words",
            "palabras",
            "mots",
            "I love cats"
          ),
          helpText
        ),
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel a bit stupid now...

For posterity:

```
        lapply(
          c(
            lapply("FAQ", shiny::h3),
            "text",
            "more text",
            lapply("Title", shiny::h3),
            "words",
            "palabras,
            "mots",
            "I love cats"
          ),
          helpText
        )
```